# Why not any Exceptions or Errors if e.g. properties on objects in JSF EL don't exist?

Tags: jsf, el

Any idea how to change this? For example:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{someBean.definitelyNonexistentProperty}">
       ... 
</ui:fragment>
```

I'm not getting any Error or any warning or anything whatsoever! Just nothing!

Sort of su...boptimal for debugging..

Is this normal? Any idea how to change this?

**Environment:** JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA, JSF Implementation: Mojarra 2.1.19

Comment: It should throw a `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException`. Is this on page load? Or is this section conditionally shown on an ajax request? If the latter, then indeed additional configuration needs to be done as to exception handling.

Comment: @BalusC oh interesting, it is indeed upon an ajax request. Why would one want to have something important like this enabled optionally??

Comment: As I guessed. See duplicate.